# How use an array of strings to create multiple ActiveRecord objects at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, refactoring, splat

I have an array of strings:

```
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]
```

I'd like to create a Day in the database named after each of these:

```
days.each do |day|
  Day.create(name: day)
end
```

This isn't so cute, however. In the past, I have been able to clean up lists of attributes by passing them into attr_accessor with a splat:

`attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES`

I am looking to be able to do something like this:

```
Day.create(name: *days)
```

Is a similar interface available for ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create them in one go:

```
Day.create(days.map { |day| {name: day} })
```

[`create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create) docs mentioned:

> Creates an object (**or multiple objects**) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The attributes parameter can be either a `Hash` or an `Array` of `Hashes`.

Comment: Thanks for this! Answers the question exactly. However, my real use case calls for #find_or_create. After looking at the documentation for #find_or_create, it does not appear to have the same functionality. Are you seeing the same?

Comment: @DylanRichards I am seeing the same. `find_or_create_by` will not create a multiple objects at one go. But you can do apply some other tricks..